# Parsing and retrieving information from JSON in Java -- JSONObject vs. JSONArray?

Tags: java, json

I'm just starting to mess around with some web programming, and am trying to retrieve information about certain musical artists from a music website's API. I'm using the JSON.simple toolkit found [here.](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/)

Here's my code. Two classes, one is `JSONReader`:

```
import org.json.simple.*;
import org.json.simple.parser.*;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class JSONReader {

private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cp;
    while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
      sb.append((char) cp);
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }

public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, ParseException {
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
    try {
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
      String jsonText = readAll(rd);
      Object obj = parser.parse(jsonText);
      JSONObject result = (JSONObject) obj;
      return result;

    } finally {
      is.close();
    }
  }

}
```

Okay, and here's my `Main` class:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Starting execution of program...");
    String searchQuery = args[0];
    JSONReader reader = new JSONReader();

    System.out.println("Beginning HTTP request...");
    String baseURL = "http://api.discogs.com/database/search?q=" + searchQuery + "&type=artist";

    JSONObject json = reader.readJsonFromUrl(baseURL);
    System.out.println(json);
```

The print statement at the end of the `main` gives me this:

```
{"results":[{"id":22898,"title":"Tool","type":"artist","resource_url":"http:\/\/api.discogs.com\/artists\/22898","uri":"\/artist\/Tool","thumb":null},{"id":5481,"title":"DJ Tool","type":"artist","resource_url":"http:\/\/api.discogs.com\/artists\/5481","uri":"\/artist\/DJ+Tool","thumb":null},{"id":186087,"title":"Tool (3)","type":"artist","resource_url":"http:\/\/api.discogs.com\/artists\/186087","uri":"\/artist\/Tool+%283%29","thumb":null},{"id":108078,"title":"Rave Tool","type":"artist","resource_url":"http:\/\/api.discogs.com\/artists\
```

with about a dozen more artists, all distinguished individually by curly braces with commas in-between.

So I "get" the `results` by doing:

```
System.out.println(json.get("results"));
```

And end up with:

```
[{"id":22898,"title":"Tool","type":"artist","resource_url":"http:\/\/api.discogs.com\/artists\/22898","uri":"\/artist\/Tool","thumb":null},{"id":5481,"title":"DJ Tool", ... ]
```

The problem is, I want to be able to, say, extract all dozen or so artists from the search result.

I cast the above to a `JSONArray` as below, and I can then 'get' indexes of the search result. My question, after this long post, is: why is this? What, essentially, is the point of the `JSONObject` in the first place, if it needs to be a `JSONArray` for accessing index of the results to work? Also, is there a reason I can't set the result of parsing `jsonText` directly to a `JSONArray`? When I try and change all of the "JSONObject"s in the `readJsonFromUrl` method to `JSONArrays`, an error occurs, saying that it is unable to cast a `JSONObject` to a `JSONArray`. Why is this?

```
JSONArray json1 = (JSONArray) reader.readJsonFromUrl(baseURL).get("results");
System.out.println(json1);
System.out.println(json1.get(0));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is simply the structure of your JSON input data: it is a JSON object with only a `results` property, whose value is an array, this array containing the data you actually want.

Since you have an object, whose single property is an array with the data that you want, you must parse the whole object to get at the array.

This seems like a rather trivial object having only a single property, but this isn't uncommon in JSON responses, indeed in any sort of network communication: the result that you actually want is wrapped in an object that will sometimes contain additional properties that provide meta-information associated with the actual result data.

Think of this outer object as an *envelope* that contains your result.

You can make the result of parsing the response - the result of your `readJsonFromUrl` method - the array, by discarding the outer object in your read method, but sometimes there will be more to the containing object that you might want to preserve, for instance some header data/meta-information that comes along with the results list, that may influence how you use the data.

Comment: Ahhhh, I see. Thank you so much! So I get that the data I retrieved was a JSON Object (denoted by the curly braces, I presume,) and its results property was a JSONArray.

Am I correct in saying that JSON responses vary in directly returning both JSON Objects and JSONArrays? Is returning, say, a JSONObject like in my case, a more frequent thing for APIs to do?

Comment: yes typically APIs will return JSON objects as an outer wrapper, which allows including header/metadata info along with the actual results. as a simple example: suppose the API limited the number of artists that can be returned in a single call to e.g. 50. along with the `results ` it would also have a `hasMore` field, or a `remainingCount` field in the object to let the caller know when more data is available.